# Java Rotation Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, rotation

I work in a small energy company and i was asked to create a method that would be called to determine which of our technicians would take home the company off hours phone.

we have 2 tables i could consider

the Technicians table

```
id           name
--------------------
001         George
002         James
003         Wesley
004         Horace
005         Jason
006         Nice
```

the Leaves table

```
id        leaveDate
--------------------
005       2020/12/29
005       2020/12/30
002       2021/01/05
002       2021/01/13
003       2021/01/13
005       2021/01/22
```

History table *not existing yet

```
id        techPhoneDate
--------------------
001       2021/01/04
003       2021/01/05
```

i could create a new table with the phone history to keep tabs on who historically were assigned to it, i just want to have something that would make sure the rotation is fair and would skip the person if on leave and would assign them on the next possible day

i already have code that would return an error if its a weekend, and if the history table already has a calculated technician for that day, it would just return that technician. it should also consider in calculation if a new technician would be added.

I initially thought it would be an easy method, but how could i go about finding who's in charge of the phone for today?

```
private List<Technicians> techs;
private List<PhoneHistory> phoneHistory;
private List<Leaves> leaves;


public RotationResponse getTechOnDuty(String rotationDate) {

        RotationResponse resp = new RotationResponse();

        try {

        resp.setRotationDate(rotationDate);
        //check if its a weekend
        resp = validateDate(resp);

        if (resp.getErrorMessage() != null) {
            return resp;
        }

        String techId = findTechIdForDate(rotationDate); // find in history if there is an existing tech already calculated

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(techId)){
            resp.setTechnician(findTechById(techId));
        } else {
            resp.setTechnician(findTechById(getTechPhoneRotationForToday(rotationDate)));
        }


        return resp;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return resp.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }


    }


private String getTechPhoneRotationForToday(String rotationDate){
// TODO
}
```

Comment: any code for us to take a look ?

Comment: *"we have **2** tables i could consider"* Then you show **3** tables.

Comment: To find the tech for a given day, first eliminate all those out that day, then for the rest calculate the number of days since they've had the phone, if they've never had it use Integer.MAX_VALUE, then take the one with the highest value. In the case of a tie pick at random, go alphabetically, or round robin, whatever you prefer. In the case where all technicians are on leave, hire more technicians or cancel someone's leave. ;)

Comment: Finding the most recent date someone has had the phone means getting the top 1 row from the history table where the id matches their id, ordered by date descending, which is a pain. I would add a third, nullable column to the technicians table with the last date they had the phone. (Or non-nullable with a default of 1970/01/01 or something.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

- keep a table with team join and leave dates for each technician (when did they start working for the company)
- define a period to analyze for making a decision, e.g. the past year
- iterate through that period and for each workday:

  - count the # of technicians in the team on that day
  - calculate the proportional phone 'obligation' as 1 / # of technicians
  - sum this obligation for each technician
- deduct 1 from that 'obligation sum' for each day where the technician had phone duty
- then assign for the next day the technician who is not on leave and has the highest obligation
- probably also avoid consecutive duty days: use the person with the next highest obligation

determining whether a day was a workday is itself probably challenging